# Unity Animation Parameter Trigger Not Resetting

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, parameters

Well I was under the impression that Animation Trigger Parameters are supposed to automatically reset after having been set.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Script : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject go;
    public bool mouseDown = false;
    Vector2 mousePoint = new Vector2 ();
    Animator anim;

    void Start () {
        go = GameObject.Find ("SquareParent");
        anim = GameObject.Find("Square").GetComponent<Animator>();
    }


    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
            mouseDown = true;
        } else {
            mouseDown = false;
            anim.ResetTrigger ("Trigger");//  <-----------
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate(){
        mousePoint = new Vector2 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
        mousePoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePoint);
        go.transform.position = new Vector2 (mousePoint.x,go.transform.position.y);

        if (mouseDown) {
            anim.SetTrigger ("Trigger");

        }
    }
}
```

But the trigger won't "consume" itself until the whole animation has played, and after that the animation decides to play itself one more time before it stops! The only way I could prevent this from happening was by manually resetting the trigger (line pointed out above), but now its just acting like a Boolean.... so whats the point? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the reason that the animation is playing once more before stopping is because of the length of the transitions in the `Animator` window in the editor.I think the reason that the animation is playing once more before stopping is because of the length of the transitions in the `Animator` window in the editor. I don't have a full answer but I've had a similar problem before.

Comment: @gjttt1 Excellent! Things are now working properly once more, but I honestly have no idea why. All I did was delete the reset line and I screwed around with the transition, but I honestly didn't even change its length or anything. Quite Bizarre. Post this as an answer and I'll give you the deserved credit.

Comment: I was a tad busy when I commented this. I'll take a quick look and try and update my answer later tonight. Glad I could help though. Make sure you check out all the official tutorials on animation in unity though. They are incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason that the animation is playing once more before stopping is because of the length of the transitions in the Animator window in the editor.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is terribly late... but none of the other answers helped me, and I couldn't find a solution anywhere else easily. Ultimately I stumbled across it through a pile of trial and error.

Make sure Attack is a Trigger type, and not a boolean type. The easiest way to tell is if it looks like a box in the Animator window instead a circle.

It should be a circle.

In my image below, OnGround is a Boolean (which won't reset)
Attack is a Trigger, which will reset

[image]

Comment: `SetTrigger` would throw an exception if it actually were a boolean paramter .. would be very noticeable in the console ;)

Comment: I would have never figured this out without this answer - from my console, SetTrigger didn't even throw an exception to a boolean parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following function:

```
void AnimTrigger(string triggerName)
 {
     foreach(AnimatorControllerParameter p in animator.parameters)
         if (p.type == AnimatorControllerParameterType.Trigger)
             animator.ResetTrigger(p.name);
     animator.SetTrigger(triggerName);
 }
```